# Select from an union sub query and got a "join" error from vba adodb

Tags: sql, vba, join, adodb

I got an error message about "JOIN statement has a syntax error", but I didn't use "JOIN" in the statement.
"abc.csv" and "efg.csv" all have same fields of "datetime,price,change,high_low".
and I am using VBA "ADODB.Connection" of "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"

the statement is as follow:

```
SELECT
 MAX(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_from`
,MIN(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_to`
FROM ((
        SELECT
         `datetime`
        , `price`
        , `change`
        , `high_low`
        FROM `abc.csv`)
    UNION (
        SELECT
         `datetime`
        , `price`
        , `change`
        , `high_low`
        FROM `efg.csv`))
```

Comment: by the way, the union part work fine.

Comment: What are you connecting to? Your use of backticks to identify object names implies MySQL, but I am not aware of `DateValue` being a MySQL function? Perhaps try using another identfier (`', ", []`). It is also pointless selecting 4 columns within the subquery if you are not going to use them, don't do more work than you have to!

Comment: event I execute the query got same error. "SELECT * FROM ((SELECT datetime, price, change, high_low FROM abc.csv) UNION (SELECT datetime, price, change, high_low FROM efg.csv))" what ever I add aliases for each sub query.

Comment: for DateValue(), because I am useing ADODB. the follower query works fine. "SELECT
 MAX(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_from`
,MIN(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_to`
FROM (
  SELECT
   `datetime`
  , `price`
  , `change`
  , `high_low`
  FROM `abc.csv`)"

Comment: the error only went out when I try to select something from union sub queries. "select * from ((select * from a) union (select * from b))"

Comment: The error code is "2147217900 (80040e14)"

Comment: This error code indicates a syntax error, have you tried, as suggested, replacing backticks with quotation marks or square brackets? In all your comments where you have posted your working queries you have not used backticks, in the question you have. Please advise what [DBMS](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=DBMS) you are using, this could give a further insight into the cause of the error (ADODB is not a DBMS, it is a library that handles connections to DMBS).

Comment: @GarethD,thank you. I have tried replace backticks with quotation marks, but the same error... :( SELECT MAX(DateValue('datetime')) AS 'date_from',MIN(DateValue('datetime')) AS 'date_to' FROM ((SELECT 'datetime', 'price', 'change', 'high_low' FROM 'abc.csv') UNION (SELECT 'datetime', 'price', 'change', 'high_low' FROM 'efg.csv'))

Comment: is "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" a kind of DMBS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your subquery try below code

```
SELECT
 MAX(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_from`
,MIN(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_to`
FROM (
       SELECT `datetime` , `price` , `change`, `high_low`
        FROM `abc.csv`
       UNION 
       SELECT `datetime`, `price`, `change`, `high_low`
        FROM `efg.csv`
      ) t
```

I've added an alias `t` after parenthesis

Comment: thank you, I have tried add aliases, but not work, same error :C

Comment: @johnn Do you really have table abc.csv and efg.csv ?

Comment: yes, the following union parts works fine   "((SELECT `datetime`, `price`, `change`, `high_low` FROM `abc.csv`) UNION (SELECT `datetime`, `price`, `change`, `high_low` FROM `efg.csv`))"

Comment: @johnn I've changed the answer try it now please

Comment: thank you, I tried but still fail, same message. It seems just can not  do query from a unioned table. like "select * from ((select * from a.csv) union (select * from b.csv))" while "(select * from a.csv) union (select * from b.csv)" is ok.

Comment: by remove the ")" and "(" around "UNION" the query works! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need aliases for your "tables" (subqueries)

```
SELECT
 MAX(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_from`
,MIN(DateValue(`datetime`)) AS `date_to`
FROM ((
        SELECT
         `datetime`
        , `price`
        , `change`
        , `high_low`
        FROM `abc.csv`) A
    UNION (
        SELECT
         `datetime`
        , `price`
        , `change`
        , `high_low`
        FROM `efg.csv`) B ) C
```

If not that, two observations. One is that you are using backquotes, maybe copied in from a word editor. Where using single quotes, should be the regular single quote character.

Second observation is not sure why you are using the quotes here. The field names all look valid and don't require them. Try removing them and leaving the field names bare. Or if you to want the field names "quoted", I believe the syntax for your case would be either double quotes or brackets. So not `price` but "price" or [price]. If you use the single quotes it means the string p-r-i-c-e.